# How do I center a button on a table and have that table fill a container in ExtJS?

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

I am new to ExtJS and I am having trouble centering a button in a container.  I am basing my code off of the documentation on the Sencha website; however, I don't see a clear explanation for centering. below is what I have so far:

```
                items: [{
                    html: content,
                    title: 'Navigation',
                    autoScroll: true,
                    border: false,
                    iconCls: 'nav'
                }, {
                    title: 'Other',
                    border: false,
                    autoScroll: true,
                    iconCls: 'settings',
                    items: [{
                        xtype: 'container',
                        layout: {
                            type: 'table',
                            columns: 1,
                            tdAttrs: {
                                style: {
                                    layout: 'fit',
                                    padding: '5px 10px',
                                    background: 'red'
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        items: [{
                            xtype: 'button',
                            width: '100%',
                            glyph: 72,
                            text: 'Logoff',
                            scale: 'large',
                            iconAlign: 'top',
                            buttonAlign: 'center'
                        }]
                    }]
                }]
```

Here's a [screenshot](http://i41.tinypic.com/hsvw4n.jpg) of my current website.

As you can see, it is left aligned and no matter what I try, I can't seem to center it in the column.

Comment: what version of extjs are you running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a user extension for centered layout, but you can also achieve it with the following vbox layout config:

```
layout: {
    align: 'center',
    pack: 'center',
    type: 'vbox'
}
```

Comment: +1, layouts are the answer. Table layouts are rarely required.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes css overide itself, for be very basic but quick just add somes

```
 &nbsp;&nbsp;
```

Inline and before your element. It's just the html code of a blank character..

Answer (score 0):

You can add you own CSS class to button using cls property, like below

```
items: [{
        xtype: 'button',
        width: '100%',
        glyph: 72,
        text: 'Logoff',
        scale: 'large',
        iconAlign: 'top',
        buttonAlign: 'center',
        cls: 'yourclassName'
    }]
```

Then define CSS class yourClassName

Hope this helps